# Mini Add to Cart Coding

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am creating a mini shopping cart, where I displayed my item and and quantity of my item, I want to add my product price into quantity, how I can do this? 
My code is

```
enter code here

<?php
Include_once("connection.php");



?>
<form action="view.php" action ="GET">
<div align="center">
<table align="center" border="2" width= 70%>
<tr>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Product Price</th>
<th>Image</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>


<?php
$view = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from `add_cart`");
$afshan=mysqli_fetch_assoc($view);
if($afshan)
{
?>
 <td><?php echo $afshan['name']?></td>
<td><?php echo $afshan['price']?></td>
<td><img width="50px" height="50px" src="image/<?php echo $afshan['image'];?       >"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="3" step="1" value="0">   <input type="submit" name="cart" value="Add to Cart"></td><td></td>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: instead 'enter image description', you should to 'enter code', make it easy for readers to appraise the question (without having to navigate away).  Please dont use images to show code ... edit the code in the body of the question. See **[the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)** to learn how to edit your code in.

Comment: i guess better to write code example in your question, not in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $afshan['price']*$afshan['quantity']
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.